# Converted the JSON Parsing Code to Arrays and getting error

Tags: excel, vba

I was working on a project to extract the data from API and Parsing it through the relevant column. The first one is working very fine but its optimizing speed is extremely slow.

so i though to convert it into arrays for fast processing but geeting `Run-time error 9` Subscript out of range`

Your help will be much appreciated to fix the issue.

**First code with slow optimization.**

```
Dim json As Object
Dim timeEntry As Object
Dim ti As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myValue As String

Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Data)
i = 2
lastRow = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row

For Each timeEntry In json("timeentries")
    With Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
        .Value = timeEntry("projectName")
        .Offset(0, 4).Value = timeEntry("taskName")
        .Offset(0, 8).Value = timeEntry("description")
        .Offset(0, 9).Value = timeEntry("clientName")
    End With

    Set ti = timeEntry("timeInterval")
    With Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
        .Offset(0, 10).Value = ti("start")
        .Offset(0, 6).Value = ti("duration")
    End With
    i = i + 1
Next timeEntry
```

**Second code with Arrays and getting error**

```
Dim json As Object
Dim timeEntry As Object
Dim ti As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim myValue As String

Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(Data)
i = 2
lastRow = Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row

Dim dataArray() As Variant
ReDim dataArray(1 To lastRow, 1 To 12)

For Each timeEntry In json("timeentries")
    dataArray(i, 1) = timeEntry("projectName")
    dataArray(i, 5) = timeEntry("taskName")
    dataArray(i, 9) = timeEntry("description")
    dataArray(i, 10) = timeEntry("clientName")

    Set ti = timeEntry("timeInterval")
    dataArray(i, 11) = ti("start")
    dataArray(i, 7) = ti("duration")
    i = i + 1
Next timeEntry

Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(lastRow, 12).Value = dataArray
```

Comment: Noone has your data and that makes it nearly impossible to help. Have you tried to use the debugger and check where this error happens? That said: Your array starts at index 1, but your counter `i` starts at 2 - maybe this causes the error? Or maybe you have more that 12 time entries in the JSON?

Comment: Yes i used the debuger error apear on the line `dataArray(i, 1) = timeEntry("projectName")` I corrected the `I=1` but error is still same. Yes there are more than 12 entries in the JSON which is unable to count

Comment: The error you're seeing suggests that there are more `timeentries` in the json, than there are used rows on Sheet2. I'm not sure why you expect those to be the same but I'm sure you have a reason. I'd explore that assumption as that's all I can see might be wrong here.

Comment: You probably need something like (pseudo code): `ReDim dataArray(1 To json("timeentries").count, 1 To 12)` and then `Sheet2.Range("A2").Resize(ubound(dataarray,1), 12).Value = dataArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size array to number of entries

```vb
Sub demo()

    Dim json As Object, t As Object
    Dim data, i As Long, n As Long
    data = "{'timeentries':[" & _
           "{'projectName':'Name1','taskName':'Task1','timeInterval':{'start':'08:00','duration':'123'}}," & _
           "{'projectName':'Name2','taskName':'Task2','timeInterval':{'start':'09:00','duration':'234'}}," & _
           "{'projectName':'Name3','taskName':null,'timeInterval':{'start':'10:00','duration':'345'}}]}"
    
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)
    n = json("timeentries").Count
    If n < 1 Then
        MsgBox "No timeentries in JSON", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
  
    Dim dataArray() As Variant
    ReDim dataArray(1 To n, 1 To 6)
    
    i = 1
    For Each t In json("timeentries")
        dataArray(i, 1) = t("projectName") '1
        If Not IsNull(t("taskName")) Then
            dataArray(i, 2) = t("taskName") '5
        End If
        dataArray(i, 3) = t("description") '9
        dataArray(i, 4) = t("clientName") '10
        dataArray(i, 5) = t("timeInterval")("start") '11
        dataArray(i, 6) = t("timeInterval")("duration") '77
        i = i + 1
    Next
    
    ' columns
    Dim col: col = Array(1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 7)
    For i = 0 To UBound(col)
        Sheet2.Cells(2, col(i)).Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Index(dataArray, 0, i + 1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much its Unbelievable appraoch. I really appreciate the help. But there is one more issue now there are in between columns which are formulated by refrencing the JSON entries column. When code is being run all the formulaion erased automtically. that means it clear all the columns as well. where JSON is not pasted

Comment: Only update columns 1, 5, 9, 10, 11, and 7 do not overwrite the others

Comment: When reoved this line as comment `'dataArray(i, 2) = t("taskName") '5` the code stop working and getting an error of `type mismatch` on the line `Sheet2.Cells(2, col(i)).Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Index(dataArray, 0, i + 1)`

Comment: Sorry to bother you but still same error same line. Irs workinf perfectly when i excluded this `dataArray(i, 2) = t("taskName") '5` line

Comment: Yes its worling perfectly. There is some issue with my field `taskName`

Comment: @spark see update - added test for NULL values in taskName.